# String.format for removing zero after decimal

Tags: c#, razor

```
String.Format("{0:0}",100.00) // Should show as 100 // This works fine
String.Format("{0:0}",0.5) // Should show as 0.5
```

But above String.Format("{0:0}" does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need `100` and `0.5` respectively, I think the simplest `String.Format("{0}", myDouble )` or even `myDouble.ToString()` could work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this format:

```
string.Format("{0:0.#####}", 0.5m)
```

This presumes that the number cannot have more than 5 decimal places.

Another way is to use the [General ("G") Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#GFormatString):

```
string.Format("{0:G29}", 0.5m)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must use String.Format("{0:**N2**}",*your_number*).
You only need to change N2 to N1 or N0 or whatever depending on how many decimals you want to display

Answer (score 0):

I just tried with simple "{0}" as following  
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}",100.00)); 
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}",0.5));
 
these result as you required.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/J3FfOm